# Shouldn't await force execution to wait?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have JavaScript code that looks like this (using Sequelize in Node):

```
if (require.main == module) {
    (async () => {
        const my_var = await MyModel.createWithChildren('name', ['one', 'two']);
        console.log('before');
        console.log(await my_var.getChildren());
        console.log('after');
    })();
}
```

`MyModel` has a static method that looks like this:

```
static async createWithChildren(name, children) {
    const me = await Me.create({name: name});
    const child_recs = await Child.bulkCreate(children.map((child) => ({child: child})));
    child_recs.forEach(async (rec) => {
        await rec.setParent(me);
        await rec.save();
    });
    return me;
}
```

But when I execute this code, where every call to the Sequelize API is preceded by an `await`, I get the "after" log before the last child update:

```
before
Executing (default): SELECT `id` ... FROM `children` WHERE `parent_id` = 1;
Executing (default): UPDATE `children` SET `parent_id`=? ...
[]
after
Executing (default): UPDATE `children` SET `parent_id`=? ...
```

The `SELECT` is coming from, I think, the call the `my_var.getChildren()` but is logging after "before," and the empty list is because it didn't "await" for the `my_var.getChildren()` call? If everything were awaiting as I expect, the log would look something like this:

```
before
Executing (default): UPDATE `children` SET `parent_id`=? ...
Executing (default): UPDATE `children` SET `parent_id`=? ...
Executing (default): SELECT `id` ... FROM `children` WHERE `parent_id` = 1;
['one', 'two']
after
```

So if I'm "awaiting" every call, why am I not seeing that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the key factor is that the `async` function the results of your `forEach` function are not being properly awaited.

The first thing to do is to switch your `forEach` to a `map`. That will make it so that operation now returns an array of promises. For debugging, it can be helpful to put that value into a variable `promises`.

At that point you may see that those promises need to be awaited within you `createWithChildren` function.

```js
static async createWithChildren(name, children) {
    const me = await Me.create({name: name});
    const child_recs = await Child.bulkCreate(children.map((child) => ({child: child})));
    const promises = child_recs.map(async (rec) => {
        await rec.setParent(me);
        await rec.save();
    })
    await Promise.all(promises);
    return me;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not `await`ing the function you are passing to `forEach`.

Usually it's easiest to just switch to `for...of`:

```
for(const rec of child_recs) {
  await /* bla bla */
}
```

If you want to keep the functional style, switch from `forEach` to `map` and await the result with `Promise.all()`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code

```js
 child_recs.forEach(async (rec) => {
        await rec.setParent(me);
        await rec.save();
    });
```

In fact, you run "in parallel" a number of your "(rec)=>{...}" function and, then, exit from your `createWithChildren(...)` without any waiting for completion operations on child_recs.
So, if you really need to await the result of operations on child_recs replace `forEach(...)` with something like `Promise.all(...)`